# Can Gen[String] Produce Other Values?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

Given:

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.prop.Checkers
import org.scalacheck.Gen
import org.scalacheck.Gen._

object Test {
  def fooOrBar: Gen[String] = oneOf("foo", "bar")
}

class Test extends FunSuite with Checkers {

  import Test._

  test("generated String should equal 'foo' or 'bar'") {
    check( org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll(fooOrBar) { x: String =>
      x == "foo" || x == "bar"
    })
  }
}
```

Running `sbt test` returns that all tests have succeeded.

Given the above code, is it possible for `x: String`, i.e. the `String` of `fooOrBar`, of type `Gen[String]`, to equal a value other than `foo` or `bar`?

In my real-world code, I'm seeing values for my `x: String` that appear to differ from the `Gen[String]` argument to `org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll`.

So, that's why I'm asking if it's possible, for the above example, whether `x: String` can not equal `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: I needed to use `org.scalacheck.Prop.forAllNoShrink`

Comment: Shrinking doesn't play well with generators indeed. Same thing if you have filtering conditions `suchThat`.

Comment: @Eric - care to post an answer for credit? I found that `forAllNoShrink` had worked for me, but I'm not entirely sure what "shrinking" involves.

Comment: Done. I actually learned that `suchThat` was one way to fix this whereas I used to think that `suchThat` conditions were not maintained during shrinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ScalaCheck finds some data falsifying a property, it will then try to "shrink" the data to find a smaller counter-example. Unfortunately during this process some `Gen` constraints might be lost. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/129).

One work-around is to disable shrinking by using `forAllNoShrink` instead of `forAll`.

Another solution is to [specify a postcondition on the generator with `suchThat`](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/commit/2d92eb6). For example see the definition of `Gen.oneOf`

```
def oneOf[T](xs: Seq[T]): Gen[T] =
  choose(0, xs.size-1).map(xs(_)).suchThat(xs.contains)
```